# How do you get your Canadian stock information?

Tags: stocks, canada, news

I am getting into stocks and am looking for ways to keep myself updated with the best current information.

The type of sources I am looking for are:

Podcasts
Newsletters
RSS feeds
Twitter
Etc.

Basically I listen to several Podcasts mostly catered to the US. I subscribe to BNN.ca's newsletter which recaps major Market news including Canada.

I follow many random twitter people who I don't know if they are good, bad, or useless.

Answer (score 1):

I only follow the news of stocks I already own.  I use the GlobeInvest Watchlist  http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/my-watchlist/ each Friday night.    In the drop-down views choose ALL NEWS

I believe that there is a strong "grass is greaner .." effect from always looking at what other stock are doing - leading to switching just before your first stock takes off. It is only when I sell some position that I go looking at other possibilities.